# FCM Data payload received in android not in json format

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting the data payload from the firebase not in json format, instead I am getting custom key-value pairs as following format:

```
Data Payload:{image=https://www.xxxx.xxx/get-profile-picture, message=This is a test message., senderName=Mathew John}
```

I have to parse the data using Json parsing for further processing.
Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("senderName");
            System.out.println("raja" + title);
            String msg = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
            System.out.println("raja" + msg);
            sendMessage(msg,title);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh The question asked before is getting the data as Json but in my case it is in custom key value pairs.these are two different types of questions.

Comment: Check the duplicate answer, it's same question and same copied answer

Comment: see my Data payload result.it is not in json.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I am getting the data payload from the firebase not in json format

**`Yes`**, Its behaving as intended.

**Because** Data payload contains `custom key-value pairs` not a `JSON` format

> I have to parse the data using `Json` parsing for further processing.

You need to use `Map<String, String>` to convert data payload in to a `JSONObject`

check below example

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(params);
Log.e("JSON_OBJECT", object.toString());
```